# Pass parameters to Airflow Experimental REST api when creating dag run

Tags: airflow

Looks like Airflow has an experimental REST api that allow users to create dag runs with https POST request. This is awesome.

Is there a way to pass parameters via HTTP to the create dag run? Judging from the official docs, found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/api.html), it would seem the answer is "no" but I'm hoping I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no longer true with the [stable REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Overview).

You can do something like -

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/unpublished/dagRuns' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
--data-raw '{
    "dag_run_id": "dag_run_1",
    "conf": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}'
```

I understand that the question is asked for experimental API but this question is the top search result for airflow REST API.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue. "conf" value must be in string

```
curl -X POST \
    http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs \
    -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{"conf":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"}'
```

Comment: Saved my day :)

Comment: I still had trouble understanding. For future readers, this does NOT mean that you just have a regular json dictionary as the payload. You must have a json dictionary with one key "conf" and one _string_ value which must be valid json. IE json-in-json.

In my own (python) code, that meant something like this:
`payload = dict(conf=json.dumps(dict(key="value"))`

`requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)`

Answer (score 10):

Judging from the [source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoints.py), it would appear as though parameters *can* be passed into the dag run.

If the body of the http request contains json, and that json contains a top level key `conf` the value of the `conf` key will be passed as configuration to `trigger_dag`. More on how this works can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945783/how-do-i-use-the-conf-option-in-airflow).

Note the value of the `conf` key must be a string, e.g.

```
curl -X POST \
    http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs \
    -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{"conf":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"}'
```