# How to access config values when triggering Airflow DAG externally?

Tags: airflow

According to https://airflow.apache.org/api.html I can trigger an Airflow DAG like so:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"conf":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"}'
```

This seems to work ok for me, but I cannot figure out how to access the `key`/`value` stuff in the `conf` object being passed in.

I tried this:

```
something = dag.params.get("key", "unknown")
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945783/how-do-i-use-the-conf-option-in-airflow

Comment: Ah I missed that -- thanks for the pointer. Works like a charm!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I use the --conf option in airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945783/how-do-i-use-the-conf-option-in-airflow)